# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2\ln x}{x^4+x^2+1}dx$ by the residue theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, residue-calculus

The result should be $\frac{\pi^2}{12}$.

Edit: I have tried to reproduce the image, but limitations of MathJax required some reformatting. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2jvL.jpg) is the original image.
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2\ln x\,\mathrm{d}x}{x^4+x^2+1}&=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2\ln x}{\left(x^2+x+1\right)\left(x^2-x+1\right)}\\
&\text{poles}\left\{\begin{array}{}
\boxed{\textstyle\frac12+\frac{i\sqrt3}2}&\raise{5pt}{\text{lies inside}\\\text{contour}}\\
\frac12-\frac{i\sqrt3}2\\
\boxed{\textstyle-\frac12+\frac{i\sqrt3}2}&\raise{5pt}{\text{lies inside}\\\text{contour}}\\
-\frac12-\frac{i\sqrt3}2\\
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{x^2\ln x\,\mathrm{d}x}{x^4+x^2+1}+\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2\ln x\,\mathrm{d}x}{x^4+x^2+1}&=2\pi i\sum\text{Res}\\
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2\ln(-x)\,\mathrm{d}x}{x^4+x^2+1}+\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2\ln(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}{x^4+x^2+1}&=\qquad"\\
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2(i\pi+\ln x)\,\mathrm{d}x}{x^4+x^2+1}+\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2\ln(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}{x^4+x^2+1}&=\qquad"\\
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2(i\pi)\,\mathrm{d}x}{x^4+x^2+1}+2\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2\ln(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}{x^4+x^2+1}&=\qquad"\\
\end{align}
$$
We need to find the residue
Then we can compare RHS & LHS side

Comment: What do you know? What contour do you propose, what have you been shown to do previously, how do you think you might convert this integral into a more friendly form... etc. Show more working!

Comment: Hint: integrate $\frac{z^2\ln^\color{blue}{2}z}{z^4+z^2+1}$ around a keyhole contour (yes, the blue part should be there).

Comment: @J.G. I’ve actually not seen that before - how do you remove the square on the $\ln$?

Comment: @FShrike The basic idea is that, if you can prove the curved parts of the contour don't contribute, a rational $f$ satisfies$$\begin{align}\oint_\gamma f(z)\ln^2zdz&=\int_0^\infty f(z)\ln^2zdz-\int_0^\infty f(z)\ln^2(ze^{2\pi i})dz\\&=\int_0^\infty f(z)\ln^2zdz-\int_0^\infty f(z)(\ln z+2\pi i)^2dz\\&=4\pi^2\int_0^\infty f(z)dz-4\pi i\int_0^\infty f(z)\ln zdz.\end{align}$$Similarly, integrating $f(z)\ln z$ around the contour in a separate exercise easily gives us $\int_0^\infty f(z)dz$ if it's not already known.

Comment: @FShrike The whole point is *not* to remove it. Think about how the principal branch of $\log^2$ changes when you go from $\theta=\epsilon$ to $\theta=2\pi-\epsilon$.

Comment: @J.G. Nice, thank you. I personally prefer differentiating a exponential parameter to obtain the $\ln$

Comment: The problem is interesting but the OP does not show the slightest effort to work on it. Nice hint @J.G.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for editing

Comment: I am not able to find the right residue.

Comment: I have rechecked the question and (ln x) is not squared

Comment: I've voted to reopen because a recent edit has added an attempt, albeit in an unsearchable image format rather than the [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) we favour. In a subsequent comment, I'll comment on the attempt with advice on how to make further progress.

Comment: It looks like a semicircular contour that would enclose poles of positive imaginary part has been attempted. Define $A_k:=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2\ln^kxdx}{x^4+x^2+1}$ so the semicircle computes $2A_1-\pi iA_0$, whereas the keyhole contour I suggested can compute first $A_0$ (by integrating with one $\ln z$ factor), then a linear combination of $A_0,\,A_1$ (by using two). The enclosed poles are then $e^{n\pi i/3}$ with $n\in\{1,\,2,\,4,\,5\}$. I invite the OP to edit in a MathJax attempt with it.

Comment: (As you can see, this is quite involved; let me know if the question is reopened but you still need help, in which case I might write an answer. But you can actually use a semicircular contour if you like, or use each once; either way, you need to compute both $A_0,\,A_1$.)

Comment: sorry sir i didn't get much of your context but i know that we need to find the two residues for two poles( which i have noted because they lie above the real axis). Then we can compare them either side to find the integral of the question.

Comment: I suggest you to ask the same question again and edit what you have done so that you can get help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Residues**
$\newcommand{\Res}{\operatorname*{Res}}$

If we have $g(z)$ with a simple zero at $z=z_0$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\Res_{z=z_0}\left(\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}\right)
&=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{(z-z_0)f(z)}{g(z)}\tag{1a}\\
&=\frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}\tag{1b}
\end{align}
$$
Applying $(1)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\Res_{z=e^{\pi i/3}}\left(\frac{z^2}{z^4+z^2+1}\right)
&=\frac1{4z+2/z}\tag{2a}\\
&=\frac{3-i\sqrt3}{12}\tag{2b}
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
\Res_{z=e^{\pi i/3}}\left(\frac{z^2\color{#C00}{\log(z)}}{z^4+z^2+1}\right)
&=\frac{3-i\sqrt3}{12}\color{#C00}{\frac{\pi i}3}\tag{3a}\\
&=\pi\frac{\sqrt3+3i}{36}\tag{3b}
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
\Res_{z=e^{2\pi i/3}}\left(\frac{z^2}{z^4+z^2+1}\right)
&=\frac1{4z+2/z}\tag{4a}\\
&=\frac{-3-i\sqrt3}{12}\tag{4b}
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
\Res_{z=e^{2\pi i/3}}\left(\frac{z^2\color{#C00}{\log(z)}}{z^4+z^2+1}\right)
&=\frac{-3-i\sqrt3}{12}\color{#C00}{\frac{2\pi i}3}\tag{5a}\\
&=\pi\frac{2\sqrt3-6i}{36}\tag{5b}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Applying the Residues**

You had gotten
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{z^2\log(z)\,\mathrm{d}z}{z^4+z^2+1}
=2\int_0^\infty\frac{z^2\log(z)\,\mathrm{d}z}{z^4+z^2+1}
+\frac{\pi i}2\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{z^2\,\mathrm{d}z}{z^4+z^2+1}\tag6
$$
which gives
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{z^2\log(z)\,\mathrm{d}z}{z^4+z^2+1}
&=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{z^2\log(z)\,\mathrm{d}z}{z^4+z^2+1}-\frac{\pi i}4\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{z^2\,\mathrm{d}z}{z^4+z^2+1}\tag{7a}\\
&=\pi i\left(\pi\frac{\sqrt3-i}{12}\right)+\frac{\pi^2}2\left(-\frac{i\sqrt3}6\right)\tag{7b}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{12}\tag{7c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(7a)}$: algebraic manipulation of $(6)$
$\text{(7b)}$: apply $(3)$ and $(5)$ to the first integral
$\phantom{\text{(7b):}}$ and $(2)$ and $(4)$ to the second integral
$\text{(7c)}$: evaluate

We used an upper half-plane semi-circular contour in both integrals on the right-hand side of $\text{(7a)}$. Therefore, we included the residues from the poles at $e^{\pi i/3}$ and $e^{2\pi i/3}$.

Comment: Sir please explain the residues

Comment: sir thankyou for editing

Comment: I have added some explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Feynman's method to evaluate.
Let
$$I(a)=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^a}{x^4+x^2+1}dx.$$
Then
\begin{eqnarray}
I(a)&=&\int_0^1\frac{x^a+x^{2-a}}{x^4+x^2+1}dx\\
&=&\int_0^1\frac{(1-x^2)(x^a+x^{2-a})}{1-x^6}dx\\
&=&\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^\infty(1-x^2)(x^a+x^{2-a})x^{6n}dx\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^1(1-x^2)(x^a+x^{2-a})x^{6n}dx\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^1(x^{6n+a}+x^{6n+2-a}-x^{6n+2+a}-x^{6n+4-a})dx\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\bigg(\frac{1}{6n+a+1}+\frac{1}{6n+3-a}-\frac{1}{6n+3+a}-\frac{1}{6n+5-a}\bigg)
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
\begin{eqnarray}
I'(2)&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\bigg(-\frac{2}{(6n+3)^2}+\frac{1}{(6n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(6n+5)^2}\bigg)\\
&=&-\frac{2}{9}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\bigg(\frac{1}{(6n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(6n+5)^2}\bigg)\\
&=&-\frac{2}{9}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}+\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{(6n+1)^2}\\
&=&-\frac{2}{9}\frac{\pi^2}{8}+\frac{\pi^2}{9}\\
&=&\frac{\pi^2}{12}.
\end{eqnarray}
Here
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{8},\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{(6n+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{9} $$
are used.

Comment: Note that
$$I(a)=\frac\pi8\sec\frac \pi6\sec\frac{\pi a}6 \sec\frac{\pi(2-a)}6$$

Comment: Thank you for telling me this. I did not this before.